bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' that could not be found
Structure of the project is attached as image

this is WebSecurity class
java
package com.demo.springsecurity.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

}

This is Service class
package com.demo.springsecurity.service;

import com.demo.springsecurity.entity.User;
import com.demo.springsecurity.entity.VerificationToken;
import com.demo.springsecurity.model.UserModel;
import com.demo.springsecurity.repository.UserRepository;
import com.demo.springsecurity.repository.VerificationTokenRepository;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Log4j2
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Autowired
    private VerificationTokenRepository verificationTokenRepository;



    @Override
    public User registerUser(UserModel userModel) {

        User user = User.builder()
                .firstName(userModel.getFirstName())
                .lastName(userModel.getLastName())
                .role("User")
                .build();
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userModel.getPassword()));
        user = userRepository.save(user);
        log.info("User saved in db");
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveVerificationTokenForUser(String token, User user) {

        VerificationToken verificationToken = new VerificationToken(user,token);

        verificationTokenRepository.save(verificationToken);

    }
}


Do let me know if u want any other class file code to see to help me to resolve this issue.
Error :
Field passwordEncoder in com.demo.springsecurity.service.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' in your configuration.
-- i have defined that method as @Bean but still not autowired, Please tell me what wrong i am doing in this code. Thanks you.
I have annotated that method as @Bean so that i can autowired it in service class but still not working.

Your WebSecurity class is missing the @Configuration annotation, so it's ignored by Spring's component scanning. This is why the PasswordEncoder bean isn't created, and thus it cannot be autowired either.
@Configuration // Add this
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

}


Thank you so much !! Now i can continue my learning. –

You missed adding the @Configuration annotation in your WebSecurity class.
I am working on the same project and found a problem with .httpBasic(withDefaults()). Here is the corrected code that worked for me:
package com.fahim.hospital_management_system.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;


/*
 * Author: Mahady Hasan Fahim
 * Email:Fmahady000@gmail.com
 * Github:fmahadybd
 */
import com.fahim.hospital_management_system.services.MyuserDetailesService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private MyuserDetailesService myuserDetailesService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(registry -> {
                    registry.requestMatchers("/registration/**", "/").permitAll();
                    registry.requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER");
                    registry.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
                    registry.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                  // .httpBasic(withDefaults()) ??? :(
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {

        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        return myuserDetailesService;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {

        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        provider.setUserDetailsService(myuserDetailesService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return provider;
    }
}


